# Toggle sidebar in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am fairly new to angular and I am trying to use a service to show and hide my sidebar. I had the showing of the sidebar working but then realised that my sidebar close button was not part of the parent component that has the toggle button. So i decided that maybe the best way would be to use a service to control the toggling and state since it will be used by both components (potential improvements much appreciated).

The error I am receiving is : `Property 'navigationService' is private and only accessible within class 'AppComponent'.` This can possibly be solved by declaring it as public instead of private but my concern is my toggle button is in the AppComponent, so not sure about the issue(feel like i have gone wrong somewhere).

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <app-sidebar *ngIf="showSideBar; else toggleMenu" class="col-md-2 bg-dark" style="display:block; height: 100vh;"></app-sidebar>
        <ng-template #toggleMenu>
            <div class="col-md-2"><fa-icon [icon]="faBars" (click)="navigationService.toggleSideBar()" style="cursor: pointer;"></fa-icon></div>
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import{ faBars } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { NavigationService } from './navigation/navigation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [NavigationService]
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-pmo';
  showSideBar: boolean = false;
  faBars = faBars;

  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService) {}

}
```

**navigation.service.ts:**

```
export class NavigationService {
    showSidebar: boolean = false;

    toggleSideBar() {
        this.showSidebar = !this.showSidebar;
    }
}
```

Any additional ways this can be improved i will gladly take on board as right now i can see why there is a learning curve to this framework. (any additional info needed, just as**k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular you can not access private fields in the template (HTML).
I would suggest either making it a public field, or use a wrapper function.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-pmo';
  showSideBar: boolean = false;
  faBars = faBars;

  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService) {}

  toggleSideBar() {
     this.navigationService.toggleSideBar()
  }

}
```

Also, the `showSideBar: boolean = false;` you have in your AppComponent.ts won't do anything for you, since it is never set.

You could change this to a get function:

```
public get showSideBar(): boolean {
   return this.navigationService.showSideBar
}
```

This so you can still access it in your template without any issues.

This is all from memory, so I may have made a mistake, but this should fix the issues that you are having with your error as far as I remember.

Comment: That variable was from my original attempt before I trying to implement the service (thanks for pointing that out will remove). Setting it to public will work but which would you suggest is the better way to go, create a wrapper function and keep private or go for public?

Comment: @LewisBlundell I do not see a benefit in both, but that is my personal experience. I would recommend using a private method with a wrapper though. This because you want to keep a service private (as it should be injected into the component that is using it) for if you are using View-Child or something along those line. Keep in mind, that neither options is better than the other, but it is mostly just preference iirc.

Comment: If I have another component, that also changes the state of the variable why does my app.component.ts recognize the change? I click the menu icon(in app.component.html) which then shows the sidebar component. But when i click the close icon (sidebar.component.html) it does not close. I am guessing this is because it has not recognised the change to my variable in the service since the click is not from app.component.ts?

Comment: @LewisBlundell This probably has to do with [lifecyles](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). You can try using [EventEmitters](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) that use the RXJS Subject and subscriptions. You can "subscribe" to the event emitter and get the changed result in such a way. I would recommend looking at the Observable pattern for this.